# What's the latest version of Unity and Compiz in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: command-line, unity, updates, compiz, update-manager

What's the latest version of Unity and Compiz in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? I have Unity 7.2.5 and Compiz 0.9.11.3.

I wanted to know if there is any latest version of both Compiz and Unity. If so, how can I update it to the latest version of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the latest versions are

- Unity: [7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty-updates&searchon=names&keywords=Unity)
- Compiz: [1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150313-0ubuntu1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty-updates&section=all&arch=any&keywords=Compiz&searchon=names)

To install the latest versions, you have to enable `trusty-updates` in <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd>.

[image]

---

Or edit the `sources.list`

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add the lines below

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates restricted universe main multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates restricted universe main multiverse
```

to enable `trusty-updates` for all available repositories (`restricted`, `universe`, `main`, `multiverse`).

Add a `#` in front of `deb-src …` if you don't need source codes.

Comment: Ok, thanks, is there anyway to do it in the terminal or not?

Comment: It is already enabled by default.

Comment: @Adam But do not add duplicate lines, if there are these lines already.

Comment: I didn't mean to duplicate lines, I just didn't see the first one as I went back cos I went onto another page

Comment: Anyway to install 1:0.9.12 in 14.04? I've hit the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1237057